# How can I convert currency on Excel Sheet?

Tags: excel

I wanna convert currency to a specific currency on excel sheet, how can i do this. I wanna convert dollar to euro.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply multiply by a rate, eg day rate (depends on the context which is not specified)
https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=EUR

This is rather a financial than technical question.

Rgds,

W

PS Lukaku's market value is higher than Pogba's

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion